# PHP - deep search with array_column?

Tags: php, array-column

How can I do deep search with `array_column`?

For instance, I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [url] => Home
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 101
            [url] => About
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [99] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 102
                            [url] => Group
                            [parent_id] => 101
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Code:

```
var_dump(array_search(102, array_column($new_items, 'id')));
```

result:

```
bool(false)
```

I am hoping to get:

```
99
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `array_column` is not recursive, it just returns the values from the top-most array.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function that does this, you have to write a recursive function of your own.